# Consumir SOAP con jquery

Tags: jquery, soap

Saludos Comunidad estoy tratando de consumir un servicio SOAP con jquery.soap pero no se mucho del tema SOAP Y estoy un poco confundido porque me arroja  el estado bien pero no me imprime nada.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:udisBanxico soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

    $.soap({
        url: 'http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL',
        method: 'udisBanxico',
        appendMethodToURL: false,
        data: xml,
        success: function (soapResponse) {
            console.log(soapResponse.toXML());

        },
        error: function (SOAPResponse) {
            // show error
            alert('Error '+SOAPResponse);
        }
    });
});
```

Si sirve de algo haciendo pruebas este es el request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:udisBanxico soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

y el response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace="http://opnet.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">pid=3280,requestid=c1c0ed3f-24d0-4040-8580-3a782bc611b5</X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:udisBanxicoResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx">
         <result xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CompactData xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message"
xmlns:bm="http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact"
xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd
http://www.banxico.org.mx/structure/key_families/dgie/sie/series/compact BANXICO_DGIE_SIE_Compact.xsd
http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/compact SDMXCompactData.xsd" >
    <Header>
        <ID>UDIS</ID>
        <Test>false</Test>
        <Truncated>false</Truncated>
        <Name xml:lang="sp">UDIS</Name>
        <Prepared>2017-09-01 00:00:02.303</Prepared>
        <Sender id="BANXICO">
            <Name xml:lang="sp">Banco de México</Name>
            <Contact>
            <Name xml:lang="sp">Subgerencia de Desarrollo de Sistemas</Name>
            <Telephone>(01 55)52372678</Telephone>
            </Contact>
        </Sender>
        <DataSetAction>Update</DataSetAction>
        <Extracted>2017-09-01 00:00:02.303</Extracted>
    </Header>
    <bm:DataSet>
        <bm:SiblingGroup BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" TIME_FORMAT="P1D"/>
        <bm:Series TITULO="Valor de UDIS" IDSERIE="SP68257" BANXICO_FREQ="Dia" BANXICO_FIGURE_TYPE="TipoCambio" BANXICO_UNIT_TYPE="Udi">
            <bm:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2017-09-01" OBS_VALUE="5.795087"/>
        </bm:Series>
    </bm:DataSet>
</CompactData>]]></result>
      </ns1:udisBanxicoResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Gracias por su atención

Comment: ¿Por qué deseas hacerlo con jquery?

Comment: ¿estás usando esta librería? https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap

Comment: Si esa libreria. 
porque ya toda la maquetacion y animaciones esta hecha solo falta consumir ese servicio.

Comment: Es una mala practica consumir un WS desde javascript porque puedes tener problemas con permisos de red para ejecutar el WS y no creo que le vayas a dar permisos a todos tus clientes(las maquinas de los usuarios) para ver el servidor de tu web service. Lo correcto es que desde javascript invoques a una clase o función que este en tu proyecto y en un lenguaje de servidor, y en esta clase o función programes la conexión soap. De esta forma solo tienes que preocuparte por permisos de tu servidor hacia donde esta el WS.

Comment: @abrahamhs la aplicacion ya realiza llamas a una api rest hecha en laravel suguieres que en esa misma api haga la conexion soap y en la aplicacion la mande llamar con una peticion ajax normal ?

Comment: Pues si, algo así, no necesariamente tiene que ser la misma API, pero si estas  usando PHP lo debes de hacer desde ahí (desde PHP). No importa si son las funciones nativas del lenguaje, un framework o una API (la misma que estas usando u otra); pero desde javascript hacer una petición ajax normal hacia php donde tengas en alguna clase o método tu conexión al WS SOAP. Porque si lo haces de otro modo: ej. desde javascript directo al web services, tendrás que dar permisos de red de todas las maquinas de los usuarios al web service y eso no es adecuado.